# EF's annotations for relationship, based on two columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I got totally lost. I have two tables, let's say `Foo` and `Bar` they are connected via two columns. I was trying to implement code-first, data representation in EF, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly. Here is my solution:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key, Column("foo1Id", Order = 0)]
    public int Foo1Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column("foo2Id", Order = 1)]
    public int Foo2Id { get; set; }

    [Column("description"), MaxLength]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("foo1Id")]
    public Bar Bar1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("foo2Id")]
    public Bar Bar2 { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [Key, Column("barId", Order = 0)]
    public int BarId { get; set; }

    [Column("foo1Id")]
    public int Foo1Id { get; set; }
    [Column("foo2Id")]
    public int Foo2Id { get; set; }

    [Column("description"), MaxLength]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Bar1")]
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Bar2")]
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos1 { get; set; }        
}
```

After hours of failing, I got this solution, from the tool that generates POCOs automatically. I'm not sure if this is correct.

I'm confused, because.. why do I need two Bar references in Foo class? Why two InverseProperties in Bar? I was trying to do something like:

```
    [ForeignKey("foo1Id, foo2Id")]
    public Bar Bar1 { get; set; }
```

and only one `InverseProperty` in `Bar` class:

```
    [InverseProperty("Bar1")]
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

But that didn't work :/

My question is: How to implement EF data annotations, when I want to connect two tables with two FKs.

Thnkas

Comment: Are you saying you have two separate columns that foreign key back to the same table or do you have table with a composite primary key which means two columns need to reference back to the table?

Comment: Do you need data annotations? I´d recommend using the fluent api.. Ones you understood what works best and how, its much easier to maintain and read I think. Why I´m saying this: I think I´m able to give you an answer with fluent api but not with data annotations

Comment: @Joshit Thanks. I would appreciate the fluent api answer as well!

Comment: Are you trying to have a composite key (two columns treated as single key) in each table, or two unique keys in each table? I'm confused as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett Yes, two columns serving as a foreign key.